# Perl not recognised as a command

Tags: activeperl

I have installed activePerl 5.20.2 build 2002. However, when I open a command prompt window and type the command perl -v, I obtain this message: 'perl' n'est pas n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe,...i.e 'perl' is not is not recognized as an internal or external command.
In the list of programs installed, ActivePerl appears. I am confused. Can anyone help me please??

Comment: Did you install ActivePerl using the .msi file? It should have added perl to your PATH environment variable. It sounds like this is what's missing - your command prompt doesn't know where to look to find 'perl', and so it is reporting it can't find it.

Comment: Yes, it is a .msi file. I checked the PATH environment variable and I found a variablenamed "path" and having as value: C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7\miktex\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;"C:\Program Files\Zone Labs\ZoneAlarm\MailFrontier";C:\Program Files\Samsung\Samsung PC Studio 3\

Comment: I don't have a Windows server handy to test at the moment, but assuming ActivePerl installs in C:\Perl then your PATH should work - perhaps it only takes effect the next time you log in, rather than the next time a command prompt starts.

Comment: thank you very much. In fact, I have placed Pel=rl under program files or it is indicated in the path that it is under C. The problem is resolved :)